# What are the drawbacks to store path of uploaded files in one table?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am design the database schema. The user can load some kind of files as images, documents.

So I decided to create one table that contains all users uploaded files:

```
CREATE TABLE UploadedFiles (
  file_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  filename VARCHAR(255),
  type: VARCHAR(255),
  filepath VARCHAR(255),
  upload_date DATETIME,
  user_id INT(100)
);
```

Lets assume there is another table EventsPhotos:

```
CREATE TABLE EventsPhotos (
  photo_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  file_id INT,
  event_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES UploadedFiles(file_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES Events(event_id)
);
```

It is related to `UploadedFiles` table.

So, I would like some tables such as NewsPhotos, UserProfilePhotos etc. and refers to this table. I wonder about performance of this approach.

Comment: I don't see what what would be wrong, performance-wise, with this approach.

Comment: Problem is this table grows fast, so to fetch photos for concrete user can be heavy, I believe

Comment: @user13314476 Not if properly indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need more than one table?...

```
CREATE TABLE UploadedFiles (
  photo_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  photo_type  TINYINT UNSIGNED,    -- news, userProfile, event, etc
  filename  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  type:  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  filepath  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  upload_date  DATETIME NOT NULL,
  user_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(photo_id)
);
```

Then have other tables for news, userProfile, event, etc, and they each include a `photo_id`, plus whatever columns are needed for the news, etc.

If one, say, "news" needs multiple photos:

```
CREATE TABLE NewsPhotos (
    news_id INT  UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    photo_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(news_id, photo_id)
);
```

How many rows might you get?  A million?  That might work OK with what I have shown you; but let's see the queries to see if you need more indexing, etc.

Comment: Is it composed key `PRIMARY KEY(news_id, photo_id)? How then update row by this key?

Comment: Why composed key?

Comment: A "composite" key is one with multiple columns.  A `PRIMARY KEY` must be unique; I assume this _pair_ of columns is unique (but each separate column is not).  When updating one particular row, specify (`WHERE..`) the values of some `UNIQUE` key (such as the PK).

Comment: Why?  Well it meets all the criteria for a PK -- unique.  And it is simpler than adding a `id AUTO_INCREMENT` for no other reason.